# How to stop 403 and 404 http errors from facebook bots and/or refresh share cache

Tags: facebook, share, bots, http-error

I'm getting lots of 403 and 404 errors from the facebook bots after changing the directory structure on my server a few weeks ago.  Of course, such errors should be expected in this situation until the cache clears, and that has happened in most cases.  However, I'm still getting this error for a select group of share links.  I've tried repeatedly to clear the cache through the debug tool for the corresponding pages, and everything looks perfect in the output, but the bad requests keep coming.  (Lint tool: [lint tool url](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)).  Here are some examples from my logs:

HTTP Access log:

```
69.171.224.251 - - 443 [13/Jan/2012:06:22:01 -0500] "GET /web/user/images/b0/b0ahhSjq1C1oEX0TBS5gLAmcSX4wKdPT.240.jpg HTTP/1.1" 403 338
```

And http error log:

```
[Fri Jan 13 05:55:01 2012] [error] [client 69.171.228.249] File does not exist: /var/xxx/www/html/web/user/images/1/ab/abSIktLHDs3rcUPYyFtxsP8J9u7vvaVr.240.jpg
```

These IP addresses point back to facebook.

Perhaps I am linting the wrong url?  How can I find out what url these requests belong to?  Doesn't facebook stop requesting after some point and refresh its cache?  The second error above is repeated about 25 times a day for the last week.

(At this point I would not consider url rewriting.)

Comment: Either ignore them (it's no harm to your site), or redirect them to the correct content (with `301 Moved Permanently`; this will lead most spiders/automated tools to update their indexes).

Answer (score 0):

You should put up 301 Permanent redirects.  Or do some sort of url rewriting.  Either way works.

You can also be sure that your reports filter out the user agent for the linter/scraper

> **When does Facebook scrape my page?**
>
> Facebook needs to scrape your page to know how to display it around
>   the site.
>
> Facebook scrapes your page every 24 hours to ensure the properties are
>   up to date. The page is also scraped when an admin for the Open Graph
>   page clicks the Like button and when the URL is entered into the
>   Facebook URL Linter. Facebook observes cache headers on your URLs - it
>   will look at "Expires" and "Cache-Control" in order of preference.
>   However, even if you specify a longer time, Facebook will scrape your
>   page every 24 hours.
>
> The user agent of the scraper is: "facebookexternalhit/1.1
>   (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"